# terraform aws_lb getting tainted and the resource is getting recreated

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform0.12+

I am using aws_lb to create an application loadbalancer in aws. However, when I run the terraform apply, it shows that the application loadbalancer is tainted and needs to be recreated all the time.

```
 # aws_lb.mylb is tainted, so must be replaced

-/+ resource "aws_lb" "mylb" {
      ~ arn                        = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:accountid:loadbalancer/app/mylb/6aa550b5001f55" -> (known after apply)
      ~ arn_suffix                 = "app/mylb/6aa550b5001f55" -> (known after apply)
      ~ dns_name                   = "internal-mylb-5175872.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com" -> (known after apply)
        drop_invalid_header_fields = false
        enable_deletion_protection = false
        enable_http2               = true
      ~ id                         = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:accountid:loadbalancer/app/mylb/6aa550b5001f55" -> (known after apply)
        idle_timeout               = 60
        internal                   = true
      ~ ip_address_type            = "ipv4" -> (known after apply)
        load_balancer_type         = "application"
        name                       = "mylb"
        security_groups            = [
            "sg-abc",
        ]
      - tags                       = {} -> null
      ~ vpc_id                     = "vpc-xyz" -> (known after apply)
      ~ zone_id                    = "zxcdfdstestzoneid" -> (known after apply)

      ~ access_logs {
          + bucket  = "mybucket"
          ~ enabled = false -> true
          + prefix  = "access_logs"
        }

        subnet_mapping {
            subnet_id = "subnet-xyz"
        }
        subnet_mapping {
            subnet_id = "subnet-abc"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you also show your definition please?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, someone accidentally ran the [taint](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/taint.html) command against your resource. You'll want to [untaint](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/untaint.html) it to avoid unnecessary recreation.

```
terraform untaint aws_lb.mylb
```